# Doing a DataTable.Select on a DateTime avoiding DateTime - String mismatch in multiple countries?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datatable

Question for C# .Net 1.1.

How do I do a Select operation on a DataTable using a DateTime comparison and still avoid the System.DateTime - System.String mismatch, while having this comparison work in other countries' date formats.

```
string strSel = String.Format("LAST_QUEUED > '{0}'", DateTime.Now);
DataRow[] drArr = DataSetX.TableX.Select(strSel);
```

LAST_QUEUED originates as an Oracle DateTime field in the USA, read into an equivalent typed DataSet table field of type DateTime.  The Selection above is done in Spain.

In .Net 1.1, I use '{0}' and in .Net 4.0 #{0}#.  However, when we run the .Net 1.1 version in Spain I get an error, *"Cannot perform > operation on System.DateTime and System.String."* (makes sense).  If I convert to the #{0}# formatter still using .Net 1.1, then I get *"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”*, so perhaps the formatter has changed between versions.

Comment: try `String.Format("LAST_QUEUED > '{0}'", " ' " +DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+ " '";` Also show whats the format of your string in {0}

Comment: glad to hear it helped..will put as answer accept it

Comment: On further thought, wouldn't this compares strings, not DateTimes, thus giving the illusion of a Select?

Comment: if you need to compare datetime with string u need to convert it tostring

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String.Format("LAST_QUEUED > '{0}'", DateTime.Now);
```

TO

```
String.Format("LAST_QUEUED > '{0}'", " ' " 
+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+ " '";
```

Comment: I did this, but when it's German machine, the date still convert to dd.MM.yyyy automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I finally opted for was to use the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat formatter in the System.Globalization namespace.

```
string strSel = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,    "LAST_QUEUED > '{0}'", DateTime.Now);
DataRow[] drArr = DataSetX.TableX.Select(strSel);
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx